# How to make Redux Saga run synchrounous code

Tags: asynchronous, redux, redux-saga

I have the following code:

```
import * as api from '../../services/api'
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function * createProduct ({payload: data}) {
  yield put(showToast('info', 'Creating product...'))
  try {
    let result = yield call(api.createProduct, data)
    if (result.success) {
      yield put({type: 'REDUX_CREATE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS'})
      yield put(showToast('success', "Product created!!"))
    }
  } catch (error) {
  }
}
```

My api.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3022/v2'
})

function createProduct (payload) {
  return instance.post('products', payload).then(({data: result}) => {
    return result
  })
}
```

But looks like line 5 and 10 are run in same time. I mean, I was expecting to my code at line 10 run only after actually fetching the API call. So this should at least take some milliseconds.

My question is: How can I make this code synchronous, showing first the line 5 (first toast message), and then show second toast only when the API call is done.

Comment: The question is wrong and likely misleading. Asynchronous code cannot be made synchronous. because it's **a**synchronous. You meant 'sequential', didn't you?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I want to wait the API fetch, and after, get the result, if success, then I run line 7. @estus

Comment: I'm still learning Saga but doesn't put.resolve do what you want? https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#putresolveaction . Also make sure that you return a promise to wait for.

Comment: @estus please look my question, I've added some code so you can better understand what comes from api.js

Comment: To me it looks like you are missing an `export` in front of your `createProduct` function.

Comment: i'm not seeing anything wrong about your code. `yield call` will run first and block the iterator until it has a response, then it'll run your if-block. if you're testing this code locally, there likely won't be any perceptible delay.